# Transforming mpl vector with own function

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, boost-mpl

I want to multiply each element in an `mpl::vector` by an `int`.
First, a  metafunction to multiply an `int_` with an `int`.

```
template <int i>
struct multiply_scalar
{
    template<typename T> struct apply
    {
        typedef int_<(T::value * i)> type;
    };
};
```

Here are the calls I want to make.

```
typedef vector<int_<3>, int_<4> > my_vec;
typedef typename transform< my_vec,  multiply_scalar<2> >::type my_vec_2;

typedef vector<int_<6>, int_<8> > my_vec_3;

BOOST_MPL_ASSERT(( boost::is_same< my_vec_2, my_vec_3 > )); //Fails
//type of my_vec2 is: boost::mpl::v_item<mpl_::int_<8>, boost::mpl::v_item<mpl_::int_<6>, boost::mpl::vector0<mpl_::na>, 0>, 0>
```

Why isn't the resulting vector simply a `vector<int_<6>, int_<8>>`? Am I holding it wrong? Probably the metafunction or the transform is not applied in the right way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mainly because of some implementation issues in C++03, the writers of the MPL 
had to use non-obvious techniques for representing sequences, one of which is
the usage of types like

```
boost::mpl::vector0<>
boost::mpl::vector1<T>
boost::mpl::vector2<T, U>
... etc
```

Instead of simply writing

```
boost::mpl::vector<>
boost::mpl::vector<T>
boost::mpl::vector<T, U>
```

as one would do with variadic templates in C++11 and beyond. Another technique
is to create some kind of reverse linked list when you insert stuff in a vector, 
which is what you're looking at in your example:

```
boost::mpl::v_item<mpl_::int_<8>, // 2nd element
    boost::mpl::v_item<mpl_::int_<6>, // 1st element
        boost::mpl::vector0<mpl_::na>, 0>, 0> // empty list
```

Because of this, the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/transform.html) 
for `boost::mpl::transform` does not specify *exactly* what is the type of `boost::mpl::transform<s,op,in>::type`. 
Actually, it only guarantees that it's a type equivalent to

```
typedef lambda<op>::type f;
typedef lambda<in::operation>::type in_op;

typedef fold<
      s
    , in::state
    , bind< in_op, _1, bind<f, _2> >
    >::type r; // <-- the return type is equivalent to this r
```

This probably does not help you unless you already know the MPL well enough that
you don't ask questions on SO about it ;-), so basically it means that it returns
a new type that's like a `boost::mpl::vector`, except for its actual type which may 
be anything like I showed above. In particular, this type is guaranteed to be a model
of the [Forward Sequence](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/forward-sequence.html) concept.

When you use `boost::is_same<T, U>`, you're actually asking whether `T` and `U`
are *precisely* the same types. You should now see clearly why this is not what
you actually want. Instead, you want to do some kind of *deep* comparison of those
two sequences, which both represent vectors. To check whether two Forward 
Sequences are equal, you must use the [`boost::mpl::equal`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/equal.html) 
algorithm instead. The following will work:

```
#include <boost/mpl/assert.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/equal.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/int.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/transform.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/vector.hpp>


using namespace boost::mpl;
template <int i>
struct multiply_scalar
{
    template<typename T> struct apply
    {
        typedef int_<(T::value * i)> type;
    };
};

typedef vector<int_<3>, int_<4> > my_vec;
typedef transform< my_vec,  multiply_scalar<2> >::type my_vec_2;

typedef vector<int_<6>, int_<8> > my_vec_3;

BOOST_MPL_ASSERT(( boost::mpl::equal< my_vec_2, my_vec_3 > ));
```