# generate mpl::vector<> of keys from a mpl::map

Tags: templates, boost, template-meta-programming

can anyone tell me why below assert fail?

quesiton 1:

```
   typedef mpl::map<mpl::pair<int, unsigned>, mpl::pair<char, unsigned char> > m;
   typedef mpl::fold<m, mpl::vector<>, mpl::push_back<mpl::_1, mpl::first<mpl::_2>>>::type keys; 
   BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT((std::is_same<boost::mpl::vector<int, char>, keys>::value == 1));
```

question 2:
     if i want to write a fold function to product a mpl::vector of the pointer to the key of the map, how should i write it?

```
template <typename T>
pointer_type {
    typedef T*  pointer_type;
}
       typedef mpl::fold<m, mpl::vector<>, mpl::push_back<mpl::_1, pointer_type<mpl::first<mpl::_2>>>::type>::pointer_type
> keys;
```

seems not working.  the mpl::_2 is never evaluted.

Answer (score 1):

The `mpl::vector` is more a convenience type from the pre C++11 era. The `mpl::push_back` operation does not return such a vector but a sequence that can grow without requiring variadic templates.

[This](http://ideone.com/4Q2wF3) little test program demonstrates what gets returned.

A detailed explanation can be found in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26683599/228841) answer.