# Tag dispatching with transformed `boost::mpl::vector`s

Tags: c++, visual-c++, template-meta-programming, boost-mpl, tag-dispatching

I am trying to tag-dispatch into a function with a reversed copy of a `boost::mpl::vector`:

```
using InitOrder = boost::mpl::vector<
    struct Foo,
    struct Bar,
    struct Baz
>;

template <class... Stuff>
void initialize(boost::mpl::vector<Stuff...>) {
    // Initialize in-order
}

template <class... Stuff>
void destroy(boost::mpl::vector<Stuff...>) {
    // Exit in-order
}

void initializeAll() {
    initialize(InitOrder{});
}

void destroyAll() {
    destroy(typename boost::mpl::reverse<InitOrder>::type{});
}
```

[Coliru demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a12d37844025ecda)

As you can see, the goal is to have two processes in `initialize` and `destroy` that have access to the `Stuff` pack. However, as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26683599/3233393), `boost::mpl::reverse<InitOrder>::type` is actually *not* a `boost::mpl::vector`, and the dispatching fails:

```
main.cpp:27:2: error: no matching function for call to 'destroy'
        destroy(typename boost::mpl::reverse::type{});
        ^~~~~~~
main.cpp:18:6: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'vector' against 'v_item'
void destroy(boost::mpl::vector) {
     ^
```

- How can I operate on a type list in both directions easily?
- Is Boost.MPL inherently incompatible with variadic templates?

I can ditch Boost.MPL if needed, provided the alternative is standard or Boost. I'm using MSVC 14.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is Boost.MPL inherently incompatible with variadic templates?

Basically. `MPL` predates C++11, so to use MPL, you *need* to use their algorithms - so their Sequence concept with their Iterators, etc. There's almost certainly a really short, clever way to do this, but I can only ever find those out with guess and check.

---

At least, if all you need to do is reverse, this is straightforward to implement in C++11:

```
template <typename...> struct typelist { };

template <typename TL, typeanme R>
struct reverse_impl;

template <typename T, typename... Ts, typename... Us>
struct reverse_impl<typelist<T, Ts...>, typelist<Us...>>
: reverse_impl<typelist<Ts...>, typelist<Us..., T>>
{ };

template <typename... Us>
struct reverse_impl<typelist<>, typelist<Us...>>
{
    using type = typelist<Us...>;
};

template <typename TL>
using reverse = typename reverse_impl<TL, typelist<>>::type;
```

So given:

```
using InitOrder = typelist<struct Foo, struct Bar, struct Baz>;
```

Then `reverse<InitOrder>` would be `typelist<struct Baz, struct Bar, struct Foo>`, and so would be usable in the way you'd want.